# Passing a null value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

Any suggestions would be awesome!

I keep getting a null value for my ClassID. When I add breakpoints, I can see the value ClassID being passed correctly, but when my program goes back to get a list I created, the ClassID returns null after stepping into that particular breakpoint. I believe my issue is in my controller, but I cant seem to find the issue.

Here is my DB file. The first dataset retrieves my ClassID from a stored procedure and my list below that returns the students in a particular ClassID

```
public DataSet GetClass(string ClassID)

    {
        ClassModel classes = new ClassModel();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("sp_ABEAttendanceEnrollment", ABEAttendanceDB);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClassID", ClassID);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds1);
        return ds1;
    }
    public IEnumerable<ClassModel> ClassModel
    {
        get
        {
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ABEAttendanceDB"].ConnectionString;
            List<ClassModel> students = new List<ClassModel>();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                ClassModel classes = new ClassModel();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_ABEAttendanceEnrollment", ABEAttendanceDB);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClassID", classes.ClassID);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds1);
                ABEAttendanceDB.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    ClassModel student = new ClassModel();

                    student.ClassID = rdr["ClassID"].ToString();
                    student.SID = rdr["SID"].ToString();
                    student.FullName = rdr["FullName"].ToString();
                    students.Add(student);
                }
                ABEAttendanceDB.Close();
                return students;
            }
        }

    }
```

Here is my controller

```
public class ClassController : Controller
{

    DAL.DB dblayer = new DAL.DB();

    public ActionResult Class(ClassModel ClassModel)
    {

        DataSet ds1 = dblayer.GetClass(ClassModel.ClassID);
        ViewBag.general = ds1.Tables;

        ViewBag.Message = TempData["Message"];
        DB classes = new DB();
        List<ClassModel> students = dblayer.ClassModel.ToList();

        return View();
    }


}
```

Comment: Is `ClassID` public with a getter and setter in `ClassModel`?

Comment: "I keep getting a null value for my ClassID." Which line in the program you pasted? "When I add breakpoints, I can see the value ClassID being passed correctly," Which line?

Comment: @TravisJ   Yes, ClassID is public. Thank you!

Comment: @aquinas both parameter.addwithvalue in my dataset and IEnumerable get the correct ClassID, but once my program goes to retrieve my list from my controller, my ClassID becomes null. Hope that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming the line you're talking about is here:

`ClassModel classes = new ClassModel();
<snip>
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClassID", classes.ClassID);`

You create a new ClassModel and then use ClassID without ever assigning anything to it. I'm assuming that's the part you're talking about that's null?

Comment: @aquinas yes, classes.ClassID passes a null value after hitting my controller. I’m not exactly sure how to pass or assign the value to ClassID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DAL code is bit strange. Surely the `GetClass` method should return the `IEnumerable<ClassModel>`? Otherwise it just looks like you end up executing `sp_ABEAttendanceEnrollment` twice for no real reason. Putting a SQL query in a getter is rather unusual, to say the least. It's also not clear why you would need two copies of your data (one as a collection of `DataTable` via `ViewBag.general` and one as a `List<ClassModel>` via the `students` variable.

I'm not sure you need the `ClassModel` property on your DAL class at all. Just make the `GetClass` method read the data into an `IEnumerable<Class>` directly, and return it to the controller. Then you can return the list of students to the controller as the model for your view, something like this:

DAL:

```
public List<ClassModel> GetClass(string ClassID)
{
    List<ClassModel> students = new List<ClassModel>();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_ABEAttendanceEnrollment", ABEAttendanceDB);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClassID", ClassID);
    ABEAttendanceDB.Open();
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        ClassModel student = new ClassModel();
        student.ClassID = rdr["ClassID"].ToString();
        student.SID = rdr["SID"].ToString();
        student.FullName = rdr["FullName"].ToString();
        students.Add(student);
    }

    ABEAttendanceDB.Close();
    return students;
}
```

Controller:

```
public class ClassController : Controller
{
    DAL.DB dblayer = new DAL.DB();

    public ActionResult Class(ClassModel ClassModel)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = TempData["Message"];
        List<ClassModel> students = dblayer.getClass(ClassModel.ClassID);

        return View(students);
    }
}
```

The view would then start with:

```
@model List<ClassModel>
```

Comment: This worked! This makes complete sense from what I was doing. Thanks!!

Comment: @DilbarC No problem...please consider marking the answer as "accepted" if it helps you (click the tick next to the question so it goes green) - thankyou :-)